# jq: read value of a key using arguments (variable key name) from json

Tags: json, jq

I have a json like this:

myfile.json

```
{
    "kind": "Configuration",
    "data": {
        "foo.xml": "\u003c?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?\u003e\n\u003cconf\u003e\n \u003c/conf\u003e\n",
        "bar.xml": "\u003c?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?\u003e\n\u003cConfiguration\u003e\n \u003c/Configuration\u003e\n",
        "abc.properties": "transaction=true"
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to get the value of the key "bar.xml"

This command does the job and I'm getting the expected output:

```
$ jq -r  '.data."bar.xml"' myfile.json 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
 </Configuration>
```

However, the key name could change. So I will have the key name in a variable

`export KEY_NAME=bar.xml`

Trying to use this variable in jq command and haven't been able to figure out the right way.

Tried below commands but working

```
$ jq --arg a $KEY_NAME -r  '.data."$a"' myfile.json 
null

$ jq --arg a $KEY_NAME -r  '.data.$a' myfile.json 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data.$a      
jq: 1 compile error

$ jq --arg a $KEY_NAME -r  '.data.[$a]' myfile.json 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data.[$a]      
jq: 1 compile error

$ jq --arg a "$KEY_NAME" -r  '.data.$a' myfile.json 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data.$a      
jq: 1 compile error
```

Could you please help me with a right command?

Comment: Almost! Try `jq --arg a "$KEY_NAME" -r '.data[$a]' myfile.json` or `jq --arg a "$KEY_NAME" -r '.data."\($a)"' myfile.json`.

Comment: both of your commands work great. Thanks a lot